# Clear-Content : Access to the path is denied

Tags: powershell, steam

I'm trying to delete my saves for steam cloud saved games, and I was told to do this, but I'm getting an error.

I run CMD as Admin, and type "powershell". I then type the following command:

```
clc "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\userdata\117436782\91310\remote\*"
```

After that, I get this error:

```
Clear-Content : Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\userdata\11743
6782\91310\remote\out' is denied.
At line:1 char:14
+ clear-content <<<<  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\userdata\117436782\91310\re
mote\*"
+ CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Program File...1310\remote
\out:String) [Clear-Content], UnauthorizedAccessException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ClearContentUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.Po
werShell.Commands.ClearContentCommand
```

I don't know how to fix this issue, so some help would be awesome!

Comment: Perhaps you can copy the files out of there to a temp folder, run clc on them and then copy them back?

Answer (score 0):

Check if there are any steam processes active. If there are, they have a lock on the files and windows won't let you do anything.
Make sure all instances of Steam and any Services it runs are stopped then try the clear.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to check that the names of your saves do not contain spaces in them. If you're merely trying to create a variance in your save compared to the cloud pick one save (that doesn't have a space) and use the command on that one. It should work.